# Preference class

Tags: java, preferences

I am now trying to use Preference class using

Preferences pfrOfThis = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(this)

It gets an error:

"method userNodeForPackage in class java.util.prefs.Preferences cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Class
  found: myPac.MainApp
  reason: actual argument myPac.MainApp cannot be converted to java.lang.Class by method invocation conversion

Leaking this in constructor"

MainApp here extends JFrame. How comes it is not a Class and could not be used here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference "this" is to an object. Try "this.getClass()".

Answer (score 3):

"this" isn't a class, it's an instance. Try .getClass(), or use MainApp.class.

Answer (score 1):

D T, if you take a look at [userNodeForPackage()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#userNodeForPackage%28java.lang.Class%29) doc you will see that signature of that method is is: `public static Preferences userNodeForPackage(Class<?> c)` which means it expect a Class object as argument. I do not know what your program does, but judging from the exception you mentioned you should try: `Preferences pfrOfThis = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MainApp.class);`